# Accessing 'checked' state for checkbox using Angular field binding

Tags: angular

Using Angular 5.1.1, I am attempting to call a function when a checkbox changes. This method works fine for `text` types but for `checkbox` input types it always sends the value of "**on**" to the function even when the box is unchecked. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="enabled" [checked]="score?.enabled" #enabled (change)="OnFieldChanged(enabled.value)" />
```

Here is the component

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'score',
    templateUrl: './score.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./score.component.less']
})
export class ScoreComponent {
    public score: IScore;

    constructor() {
    }

    OnFieldChanged(value: string): void {
        var fieldValue = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of trial and error, I found the solution. You have to apply the field to `[(ngModel)]`. Simply passing `OnFieldChanged(judge)` also did not work since the boolean property was never actually updated

```
<input type="checkbox" name="enabled" [checked]="score?.enabled" (change)="OnFieldChanged(judge.enabled)" [(ngModel)]="score.enabled" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just access score via the function as follows,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="enabled" [checked]="score?.enabled" #enabled (change)="OnFieldChanged(score)" />
```

and inside TS

```
OnFieldChanged(value: string): void {
        var fieldValue = value.enabled;
}
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I am looking for. I am trying to create a reusable function allowing me to capture individual input field value changes and not the whole object

Comment: i dont think  you can achieve that